# FopFactory missing methods

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-fop

Recently I faced problem with PDF generation that some glyphs was represented with '#'. I made my own fop config file and tried this:

```
fopFactory.setUserConfig(new File("path/to/config.xml"));
```

But it seems like `fopFactory` doesn't have method `setUserConfig`.

Also I tried this:

```
fopFactory.getFontManager().setFontBaseURL(fontBase);
```

But result is the same - `FontManager`doesn't have method `setFontBaseURL`.

My maven dependency is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
    <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Tried to add jar manually but that didn't change the thing.

Found [here](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.1/upgrading.html) how to use user configs but the struggle is that I need to use xsl template in constructor `newInstance()`. How is it possible to set both xsl (note: NOT XSL-FO!) and config?

Here is my code fragment:

```
    // setup xml input source
    String xml = object.toXml();
    StreamSource xmlSource = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("UTF-8")));

    // setup xsl stylesheet source
    File xslFile = new File(stylesheetPath);
    FileInputStream xslFileStream = new FileInputStream(xslFile);
    StreamSource xslSource = new StreamSource(xslFileStream);

    // get transformer
    TransformerFactory tfactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = tfactory.newTransformer(xslSource);

    // setup FOP
    FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(xslFile);
    FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();
    foUserAgent.setProducer(this.getClass().getName());
    Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent, pdfContent);

    // perform transformation 
    Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
    transformer.transform(xmlSource, res);
```

Comment: You probably found some code examples referring to older versions of FOP; in [FOP's web page about embedding](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.1/embedding.html#basics) you should find an updated example (the same page also has examples of XML + XSLT input).

Comment: @lfurini given code throws an exception that my xslt is invalid when it is normally valid.

Comment: When you call `FopFactory.newInstance()` you have to pass as a parameter the **configuration file**, not the XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

As `lfurini` pointed out, `setFontBaseURL()` disappeared in some pre-2.0 version of Apache FOP. Most programmatic configuration is now done using [FopFactoryBuilder](https://users.edu.turku.fi/tv0683/xml/harjoitusty%C3%B6/fop/javadocs/org/apache/fop/apps/FopFactoryBuilder.html). Also see [Apache's guide to upgrading to FOP 2.1](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.1/upgrading.html).

Answer (score -1):

`FOPFactoryConfigurator` class has been removed, `fopFactory.setUserConfig(cfg)` is not available anymore. This is when you use newer than (1.x or earlier version of fop)

check this https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.1/upgrading.html